# How to use an array in RISC-V Assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv

I'm learning RISC-V assembly and i need to use array for an exercise that i'm solving; the problem is that the simulator that i'm using([RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars)) gave me an error:
`Error in /home/username/file_name line 8: Runtime exception at 0x00400010: address out of range 0x000003e8.`

This is the code i wrote so far:

```
.data
arr: .word 1000
e0: .word 5

.text
lw t1, arr # load arr into t1
lw t2, e0 # Load e0 value into t2
sw t2, 0(t1) # save t2 value into arr[0]
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instruction `sw t2, 0(t1)` stores the content of the register `t2` into the memory address provided by the register `t1`. However, `t1` does not contain the address that corresponds to the label `arr` – the address where the value `1000` is stored – because `t1` was initialized by the instruction `lw t1, arr`, and this loads the **content** of the address corresponding to `arr` into `t1`, i.e., it loads the value `1000` into `t1`.

Instead, replace `lw t1, arr` by `la t1, arr`, which does load into `t1` the address that `arr` is representing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
.data
arr: .word 1000
e0: .word 5

.text
la t1, arr # You can only load the address of your arr into t1
lw t2, e0 # Load e0 value into t2
sw t2, 0(t1) # save t2 value into the address of arr[0] pointed by t1
```